# Nginx Docker's container : set default home page with a custom index.html

Tags: nginx, docker, home-directory

I work with docker container and i built one for nginx.

I would to change the nginx's home page with my index.html.

How can i tell to my nginx container where find my custom index.html and replace his own index.html by my index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply put a [`COPY` command](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy) or an [`ADD` command](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add) in your Dockerfile, which would copy your `index.html` file over the one provided by NGiNX (defined by the `root` directive, like `/data/www/index.html`)

```
COPY <src>... <dest>
ADD <src>... <dest>
```

Here:

```
COPY /path/to/your/index.html /data/www/index.html
ADD /path/to/your/index.html /data/www/index.html
```

Note, `RUN` or `COPY` are preferred to `ADD`:

> **The first encountered `ADD` instruction will invalidate the cache for all following instructions from the Dockerfile if the contents of `<src>` have changed**.
>   This includes invalidating the cache for `RUN` instructions.

That is why the [suggestion made in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535153/nginx-dockers-container-set-default-home-page-with-a-custom-index-html/29536079#comment47226512_29536079) is better:

> if you have few changes

```
RUN sed -i -e"s/aaa/bbb" /data/www/index.html
```

If you have many changes, `ADD` is still a valid option (try `COPY` first), but try to put it at the *end* of the dockerfile, not at the beginning or in the middle.

Comment: or a sed, an example  `RUN sed -i -e"s/aaa/bbb" /data/www/index.html` if you have few changes

Comment: @user2915097 true. I have edited the answer: `RUN` or `COPY` are better than `ADD`, which can invalidate the cache for all following instructions from the Dockerfile.